# Cannot dequeue Elementor Font Awesome css

Tags: php, css

I am using the same below code to dequeue many other styles but it is not working for Elementor, and a couple of others.

```
function enqueue_content(){
  wp_dequeue_style( 'elementor-icons-shared-0' );
  wp_dequeue_style( 'elementor-icons-fa-solid' );
  wp_dequeue_style( 'elementor-icons-fa-regular' );
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_content', 20);
```

I have also tried the method described on their support: https://docs.elementor.com/article/286-speed-up-a-slow-site

EDIT: It seems as if the styles I can't dequeue are loading from a different, parent wp-content folder (it is a multisite).

Comment: Have you tried increasing '20' to something like '100'? Also, consider installing the Debug Bar plugin(s) https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/developer-tools/debug-bar-and-add-ons/ They may be able to show you what priority the enqueue styles currently have.

Comment: I have tried increasing the number. Unfortunately it's a site where I have no access to plugins. Have just realised it's a multisite and loading from two different wp-content folders. Edited question.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue. This snippet worked for me.

```
add_action('elementor/frontend/after_register_styles',function() {
    foreach( [ 'solid', 'regular', 'brands' ] as $style ) {
        wp_deregister_style( 'elementor-icons-fa-' . $style );
    }
}, 20 );
```

You may only need the solid and regular dequeued.

```
add_action('elementor/frontend/after_register_styles',function() {
    foreach( [ 'solid', 'regular' ] as $style ) {
        wp_deregister_style( 'elementor-icons-fa-' . $style );
    }
}, 20 );
```

[Elementor Reference](https://elementor.com/help/speed-up-a-slow-site/)